# How to add a condition to form valid in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

Intro: I am creating a events app, I want the user to choose a date between 3 days from today to a maximum of 30 days from today

```
class CreateEvent(IsVerifiedMixin, CreateView):
    model = Event
    form_class = EventForm
    template_name = 'event/event_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        event = self.object
        today = datetime.date.today()
        user = self.request.user
        if today + datetime.timedelta(days=3) <= event.date <= today + datetime.timedelta(days=30):    
            event.user = self.request.user
            event.initial_stock = event.stock
            slug = self.kwargs['slug']                    
            event.save()                
        else: #I know the below line of code is wrong. How do I fix this
            messages.error(self.request, "The event date has to be equal or more than 3 days away and less than 30 days")    
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The above gives me a `IntegrityError` if the date is off if the date is correct the object is created. I just want to get a form error and the form to not go to the next page

**Below are is the form.py for this**

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    price = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    stock = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('price', 'stock', 'date', 'time_from', 'time_to', 'lat', 'lon')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple fix https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error

```
if today + datetime.timedelta(days=3) <= event.date <= today + datetime.timedelta(days=30):
    ...
    return super().form_valid(form)

else:
    form.add_error(field="date", error="The date has to be more than or equal to 3 days and less than 30 days")
    return super().form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: This is wrong. That should not go in `form_valid`; that method is called when the form is *already* valid. You should put that logic into EventForm itself, in a `clean_date` method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman what exactly do you mean by this is wrong. It is working at the moment. Will it not work for a certain scenario etc..

Comment: @DanielRoseman. Can you add the answer. I have added my forms.py in the question

Answer (score 0):

Add clean function to your ModelForm:

```
def clean(self):
    time_from = self.cleaned_data.get('time_from')
    time_to = self.cleaned_data.get('time_to')
    if #implement your logic:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Validation msg")
    return self.cleaned_data
```